# Need help in zeroing on webbased xmmp group chat client

Tags: xmpp, chat

I need a webbased group chat client that can interact with various xmpp servers.

I did some research and found muckl , speeqe and tigase minichat but I have one more issue I am deploying my site on shared hosting.

So want to know if anybody has installed any group chat software on shared hosting ( like bluehost ) and which will be the best possible client for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Speeqe is actually 99% javascript, so it will work well on shared hosting. The requirement for Django is just to do things like remember sessions and have nice url structure. It may take a small amount of work to take away Django, but it shouldn't be much.

There are also Django hosting providers, so that might be an option.

Speeqe can also work with any XMPP server, public or self-hosted, etc. I used it many times to join groupchat rooms on arbitrary servers, and there is even an IRC gateway.

For XMPP shared hosting, there are several options now, including a service by Process One: http://process-one.net

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply , Yes I am zeroing on Speeqe only. Can you help me with your .htaccess file if anything special is required in that file or any special recommendation integrating speeqe on a custome website.

Secondly I want speeqe as a chatroom additionally i need to add a chatbot to that session which can interact with user , Any suggestions on how can i do that.

Thanks a lot
Regards
Saurabh